# Netbeans Exploded EAR Development with JBoss5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss, jboss5.x

I'd like for Netbeans to deploy directly into an exploded ear in JBoss, instead of the current process of deploying a whole .ear file.  Development would be much quicker if it were possible to edit .jsps and backing beans without a redeploy after each change.

Is this possible?

Comment: Something about the phrase "deploy directly into an exploded ear" disturbs me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why not. I use Eclipse but it doesn't do anything special aside from an ant task that moves the changed files in the exploded EAR into the Jboss Deploy directory. Netbeans can definitely handle ant so should be reasonably easy.